# How to specify tmp directory for rendering

Tags: rendering

I tried to make animation rendering and saw in console

```
Saved: 'C:\tmp\0001.png'
 Time: 00:01.15 (Saving: 00:00.31)

Saved: 'C:\tmp\0002.png'
 Time: 00:01.00 (Saving: 00:00.31)

Saved: 'C:\tmp\0003.png'
 Time: 00:01.00 (Saving: 00:00.30)
```

and so on.

But I have `SSD` on `C` and don't wan't to exploit it hard. How to specify different drive for saving frames during rendering?

Neither `TMP` or `TEMP` system variable work. Reasonable fields from this dialog also ignored

[image]

Comment: You can set the output directory in the *Output Properties > Output*. For new projects on Windows this is set to `C:\tmp` by default (or `/temp\` as it is displayed in the UI). Does that answer your question? Changing the default would be done through the *Render Output* preference seen in your screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Preferences` dialog you can set the default directory for new scenes.

The **actually used output directory** can be changed in the `Output Properties`:

[image]